# Laravel autoload file variable from view

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have recently move my projects into laravel. In my projects, I have a single file which contains common variables.
My common.php file is in app/Libs/common.php

```
$a = array(
  'b' => 'c'
);
```

I also added my common file is in composer.json file.
My composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": { 
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Libs/common.php"
    ]
},
```

Now I want to access this variable in view.
My View file:

```
<?php print_r($a); ?>
```

It gives me following errors:

```
Undefined variable a (View: ...)
```

Comment: composer dump-autoload ?

Comment: I used composer dump-autoload before publishing this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variables the very wrong way. Try this:

Modify your common.php:

```
<?php return array( 'a' => array(
  'b' => 'c'
));
```

Create a common.php to your config folder, and put this there:

```
<?php return require app_path('Libs/common.php');
```

After you can use your variables:

```
config('common.a')
```

or

```
config('common.a.b')
```

If you want use only in views common your variables, you can use View composers in your providers, or you can create a priveder to share your varaibles with all view file